# No puedo usar función (onButtonClicked)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml, kotlin

He creado una función llamada "onButtonClicked" y Quiero que al presionar el botón (bt301_tw), me envíe a la actividad (MainActivity_04_ReadioGroup).

El problema es cuando creo la función onButtonClicked, no puedo usarla y No quiero usar un setOnClickListener porque estoy practicando con diferentes vistas

Mi código:

XML

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/bt301_tw"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?android:attr/colorActivatedHighlight"
            android:onClick="onButtonClicked"
            android:text="@string/rodiogroup_301" />
```

Actividad principal

```
fun onButtonClicked(view: View) {
        if (view.id == R.id.bt301_tw) {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity_04_ReadioGroup::class.java)
            startActivity(intent) 
       }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: como es eso de que no puedes usarla?? si te lleva a la otra activity??

Comment: No me esta llevando a la otra actividad.

Comment: si no te lleva, que pasa?? que marca el logcat?? tu codigo esta bien

Comment: si no te lleva, que pasa(Cuando presiono el boton (bt301_tw) se destruye la aplicación ), que marca el logcat(perdon soy principiante y no se que es el logcat, agradezco su explicación), tu codigo esta bien(Si esta bien , el unico problema que tengo, es con la función onButtonClicked, la cual cree para ir a la actividad (MainActivity_04_ReadioGroup))

Comment: En la parte inferior de Android Studio hay un botón que dice LogCat, allí se muestran los posibles errores. Revisa que la Activity MainActivity_04_ReadioGroup se encuentre declarada en el Manifest, como de seguro si lo esta la Activity MainActivity_03

Comment: En el Manifest pude encontrar esto:         <activity android:name=".MainActivity_04_ReadioGroup"></activity>

Comment: y que dice el logcat??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me funciono esto

```
fun onButtonClicked(view: View) {
        if (view == findViewById(R.id.bt301_tw)) {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity_04_ReadioGroup::class.java)
            startActivity(intent) 
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tengo mas práctica en Java que en Kotlin, pero averiguando creo que el error está a la hora de obtener el ID del botón. Utiliza esta función en cambio.

```
fun onButtonClicked(view: View) {
        if (view.getId () == R.id.bt301_tw) {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity_04_ReadioGroup::class.java)
            startActivity(intent) 
       }
}
```

Comment: Si aún no sabes manejar el Logcat puedes, en lugar de lanzar la actividad implementar un Toast, así puedes descartar si el error esta en la actividad MainActivity_04_ReadioGroup.